# application automation in MacOS (like OLE in Windows)

Tags: macos, automation, ole

In Windows, developers are able to write a program, letting it automate lots of applications (such as Photoshop, Office Word) which are not in the same process as the program itself, provided those applications support OLE.

Since many of those well-known applications that support OLE automation in Windows also come with MacOS version. I wonder if there's a similar technique that can let developers write programs that can automate other applications which are not in the same process as the program itself.

Comment: After search on the Internet for a while, I just found that it could be AppleScript(but I could be wrong). Now I am learning it.

Comment: AppleScript is a script language, just like python, so is very different from OLE automation. Can you give an example of what you a trying to automate ?

Comment: The Script Editor for Applescript will let you open an application's scripting dictionary (if it has one) and browse through the commands that application supports.

Comment: @PhillipMills For example, changing the font of the currently selected text in Office Word. It can be done using OLE automation in Windows. I am just starting looking things up in Office Word's AppleScript suite in the dictionary. I think if Word provides such functionality of changing the current font using OLE, then that makes sense that it also provides the same functionality via AppleScript.